# oracle database move current server to another machine problem

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, rman

these day i really stress because of oracle server, im quite new to oracle.

i have one old windows 2003 server which installed oracle 10.2.0 version.

and i want to full backup of this oracle then want to install same database to another

new windows 2003 server ,this windows 2003 server is all different server, computer

name and other thing.

and i was cold backuped from old 2003 server then i was copy all this file

to new 2003 server and startup but failed to startup

how can i restore in this situation?

what is exact procedure to full restore from my old windows 2003 to new 2003 machine.

or maybe how about if i copy whole oracle folder from old machine then

paste it to new machine?

is it possible ? Thanks a lot sorry my english

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do mean cold backup (shutdown database and copy files) rather than RMAN, first, restore all the files onto your new system. You will need

1. the pfile (initSID.ora where SID is the name of your database) or spfileSID.ora
2. The datafiles (likely to be .DBF)
3. The control file(s) (likely to be .CTL)

Next, edit the pfile to refer to the new location of the control file, if different.

Next, use the [ORADIM](http://psoug.org/reference/oradim.html) utility to create a new instance, referring to the pfile. Now you can start the database in MOUNT mode.

If the locations of the DBFs are different on the new system, you will need to `ALTER DATABASE RENAME DATAFILE 'old location' to 'new location';` for each one (in SQL*Plus).

Finally you can do `ALTER DATABASE OPEN` and you should be all set.