# How to move Oracle database to another PC without restoring backup?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i

Take this scenario:

Suppose the customer has no backup of Oracle 9i or 10g database. The customer wants to move the database from one PC to another. The other PC has a fresh installation of Oracle.

How to move the data and other files and attach to the new installation? In this scenario, we don't have any type of backup, neither a dump nor any other type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/193839/oracle-database-move-current-server-to-another-machine-problem

Comment: What OS/Platform?

Comment: @REW: Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/193839/oracle-database-move-current-server-to-another-machine-problem).

Answer (score 3):

Make a backup and restore it to your new Pc and make backups in the future!

Answer (score 1):

The exact way, could depend on your configuration, but roughly, you could:

**1)** Export / Import (see documentation for exp)

**2)** Cold backup:

- Make sure you have a copy of your [pfile/spfile](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/pfile_spfile.htm)
- Shutdown your source database
- Copy your datafiles to the new server

There are some steps to do in between, but the advice is to consult with an oracle DBA, or read the documentation on [otn](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/pfile_spfile.htm)